# KDE decrease opacity of active window

Tags: compiz, kde, plasma

Compiz used to have this neat effect that allowed you to see the windows below the active window by making the active window transparent when the mouse was moved outside it. 
This is similar to the Translucency desktop effect, but instead of having to move the active window, it was based on the mouse focus.

This is not the same as focus-follows-the-mouse, where the inactive window is raised above the active one. The compiz effect was just changing opacity to 10% when the active window was losing focus and back to 100% when the mouse was again over the active window.

Is it possible to re-create this effect with Plasma?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar in Kubuntu 18.04.

There are at least two ways: using the keyboard and using the mouse.

### Using the keyboard

- Open System Settings > Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts > KWin
- Scroll down to `Decrease Opacity of Active Window by 5%`, click on `Global` and then in the `Input box` and press the keys you want: I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
- Similarly, set something for the `Increase Opacity of Active Window by 5%` such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

[image: keyboard]

### Using the mouse

A second way that I know of is to use the scrollwheel of your mouse:

- Open System Settings > Window Behavior > Window Actions

  - Here, in the lower area titled "Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame", click on the dropdown next to "Mouse wheel:" and select `Change Opacity`

[image: scroll]

Here's an example: Google Chrome is the topmost, active window. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> a few times shows the InfoCenter window immediately below and a konsole window further down.

[image: sample]